# jQuery Popup position with different window size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want use JavaScript to control the popup position for a window of different size.

How can I do it?

Comment: Could you be *a tad* more specific?

Comment: Have a look at this reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are talking standard `window.open` popups, in case not please tell us.

What you'll have to do is pretty easy. First find out your client's screen dimensions using the `screen` object:

```
var screenWidth = screen.width;
var screenHeight = screen.height;
```

Now as we have screen's size we could for example use it to calculate the top left corner of a centered popup of 800x600 dimensions:

```
var top = screenWidth/2 - 300;
var left = screenHeight/2 - 400;
```

Now, we'd be ready to go:

```
var myCenteredWindow = window.open(myURL,'myFancyPopup','width=800,height=600,scrollbars=no,top=' + top + ',left=' + left + '');
```

Note that this could be easily written into one line (when you get what's happening):

```
var myCenteredWindow = window.open(myURL,'myFancyPopup','width=800,height=600,scrollbars=no,top=' + screen.width/2 - 300 + ',left=' + screen.height/2 - 400 + '');
```

Answer (score 0):

To control the pop-up dialog window in different window sizes use the width of the window and the width of your dialog to calculate the position of your dialog, **for example:** If you need your dialog to appear in the middle of the screen regardless of the window width, try this:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width(); //get the windows width;
var dialogWidth = $("#popup-dialog").width(); // get the dialog width;
var pLeft = (windowWidth - dialogWidth) / 2;
$("#dialog").css("left", pLeft);
```